# How does high-intensity aerobic exercise affect the brain?

Tags: exercise, neurology

I have been reading articles claiming that serotonin, endorphins and BDNF are produced during exercise, but they never mention the intensity or duration of exercise for this to happen.

To not make this question too broad, I want to narrow it down to, lets say, a 4-5k run over 20 minutes.

How will this affect the brain? Which chemicals do the body produce that could have an effect on the brain? And, how much?

I am asking because I am always curious about the mechanisms underlying the effects of exercise on the brain and because it's always difficult to find information regarding results of exercise; Googling mostly results in content marketing articles (like [this one for Buffer](https://www.fastcompany.com/3025957/what-happens-to-our-brains-when-we-exercise-and-how-it-makes-us-happier)). Also, I have also asked a [separate question regarding the effects of low-intensity aerobic exercise](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20583/how-does-low-intensity-aerobic-exercise-affect-the-brain).

Comment: @BobOrtiz No, this is not the same question; I didn't want the questions to get too broad, so I separated them out into low and high-intensity exercise questions. I thought that would be alright since I already wrote in the original question that I would be doing this. Since neither you nor Chris objected, I assumed I could go ahead. Sure, huge chunks of the question is copied and pasted, but they cover somewhat different issues.

Comment: To me, "affect the brain" sounds pretty broad. Narrowing down to a specific exercise type is actually not that helpful because then the only way to answer your question is to find a study using exactly that protocol, which may not be the protocol used in any study. Additionally, I think your other question is in fact the identical question the way you have phrased it.

Comment: @BryanKrause Well, yeah, it might be broad. In that case, I need a different formulation and maybe break if down a bit differently; Essentially I am looking for chemical changes that happen immediately after and during the workout, and not long term changes due to better sleep and the like. What do you think? Would that suffice? 

But, well, I do want to see the differences between different exercise intensities (but I don't care about high-intensity anaerobic workouts)